# Doesn't work debugger in IDEA 14 intelijj with GWT Tomcat server side and Jetty - SuperDevMode

Tags: tomcat, gwt, intellij-idea, jetty

I use tomcat for server side and Jetty for SuperDevMode GWT. I cliced checkbox JavaScript debugger in Jetty run Jetty with super dev mode, but debug in client side doesn't work. How to right set IDEA 14 in my situation?

Answer (score 1):

On Super Development Mode client side debugging is done on the browser.
You can find necessary info here: http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html